# Execute action on exception and return to last page visited

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using a global exception handler and in the Exception View, I give the user a chance to click a button to send the error report to us via email.

The action SendErrorReport is posted from the Error View if they click the button. In this action, I format and send an email with the exception data posted from the Exception view.

I want to then transfer the user to the page that was last visited before the exception if a certain condition does not exist.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
if(!CertainCondition)
{
    return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
}
```

More about [Request.UrlReferrer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx).

Comment: I don't really want them to go back to the same page where they clicked the button but the one before that. The Request.UrlReferrer has the value but I'm not sure how to do it, just use Redirect?

Comment: Yes, simply redirect passing to the `Redirect` method the value of `Request.UrlReferrer`.

Comment: Is there a way to get the previous page to the Referrer visited?

Comment: Think I get it from the history using javascript and then send that as a form element?

Comment: Well, this is a way of doing it... :)

Comment: Actually, you can't access the history URLs. Hmm....Maybe write a "sniffer" javascript that records all their page visits on my site?

Comment: I've never used `addHistoryPoint()`. From what I understand you should be able to pass the previous URL to your  `SendErrorReport` action method while you're in the global exception handler. `SendErrorReport` should accept a string URL parameter in this case.

Comment: I"m not sure where the error handling is occuring. I have the [HandleError] attribute on my action and added HandleErrorAttribute() fo my Global Filter.

Comment: Actually, I was able to put the referrer in the form data and now it is working like I want.